# Как перехватить запрос на удаленном компьютере в chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, запрос, ssh, google-chrome-devtools

Есть удаленный ПК в локальной сети. На нем установлен Porteus Kiosk(структура Linux'a). Имеется подключение по ssh. На удаленном ПК запускается chrome и все.
Нужно получить хотя бы 1 запрос. Интересуют xhr запросы.
На локальном компьютере понятно как это сделать, зайти в панель разработчика-сеть и глянуть какие там запросы делаются если делаются, а как это сделать на удаленном компьютере по ssh?
Если нужны еще какие-то вводные, скажите постараемся достать их

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить параметр в строку запуска браузера.

Например создать обертку /usr/local/bin/chromium

```
#!/bin/bash    
/usr/bin/chromium --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Подключиться к хосту с пробросом порта:

```
ssh 192.168.0.127 -L 9222:127.1:9222
```

Открыть на локальном компьютере `chrome://inspect`.  В discover network targets поставь `localhost:9222` и чуть ниже появится список открытых вкладок